# Sencha PhoneGap : Panel Background Image not displaying in Android apk

Tags: extjs, cordova, sencha-touch

Am facing one issue in sencha touch along with phonegap. Having 'xtype:panel' with property 'cls:topImgPanel'  under scss code where am setting background Image for panel.

Login.js

```
{
    xtype : 'panel',
    cls : 'topImgPanel',
    height : '15%',
    docked : 'top',
}
```

login.scss

```
.topImgPanel {
    background-image: url("img/TOP_Printer_HD1.png") !important;
    background-size: 100% 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This code seems to running in browsers, but when using phonegap to run it in my android emulator. Images are not visible anymore.

Not able to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some struggle, if found this [link](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/local_images_not_appearing)

As mentioned, **we need to put images into root folder**, so in my login.scss :

```
.topImgPanel {
    background-image: url("../../TOP_Printer_HD1.png") !important; //changed path
    background-size: 100% 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and i copied my image files under the directory 'phonegap/www'.

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Your image url is not ok.

In fact, the url you provide to the path of your image should be related to the location of your CSS file. So you need to change it according to your Android Phone.

Comment: i have edited my project and question putting the img folder into 'resources/css' folder as shown above.Still the issue persist with generated apk.